# Using bind(this) on a property accessed with [ ] array brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, bind

If I have some object serving as a list of functions, like so:

```
F.deltas = {
    "img": function (k, toff) {...},
    "haspect": function (k) {...}
};
```

Why can't I use bind() on them, like so?

```
F.deltas["img"].bind(this);
```

Comment: You can; what's the value of `this` (or what to you *want* it to be)?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows the problem and describe your desired outcome. There's nothing wrong wth the code you posted, so it's unclear what you need.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` doesn't change the function, it returns a *new* function, which you are throwing away. It is equivalent to asking "Why doesn't `sum + 2;` increase my `sum`". This will work (obviously, only if `this` is correct):

```
F.deltas = {
    "img": function (k, toff) {...}.bind(this),
    "haspect": function (k) {...}
};
```

or this:

```
F.deltas["img"] = F.deltas["img"].bind(this);
```

Comment: I get what you're saying. Thanks for the answer! I solved the issue by using F.deltas["img"].bind(this)() instead.